# reshape (1000,1,17) tensor into (1000,17) tensor in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Im stuck with how to transform a (1000,1,17) tensor into (1000,17) tensor.
What Im trying with sofar is `reshape` and transpose as I have seen in other answers but im not able to figure out how they work.

Im trying this (actions is my original 3d tensor)

```
actions.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(3,-1)
```

1. What do I need to change to get things working with 3d-2d?
2. How can i change back from 2d-3d in the same way?

Please provide detail since a oneliner is not much help in understanding.

Comment: you can simply assign the desired shape as long as it is compatible, like so `actions.shape = 1000, 17`

Comment: Why are you giving us a one liner, if you find that confusing?  What was the shape after the transpose?  What was the purpose of the 3 in the reshape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to do it through `reshape`, it'd be

```
actions.reshape([1000, 17])
```

You just pass in the new shape. I have no idea why you were trying to use `transpose` or passing `3` and `-1` as arguments. The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) are pretty clear.

Instead of `reshape`, it'd probably be easier to index away the length-1 dimension:

```
actions[:, 0]
```

The reverse would be

```
arr.reshape([1000, 1, 17])
```

or

```
arr[:, None]
```

There's also `np.squeeze`, which gives a view of an array with all length-1 dimensions removed, but that can remove more dimensions than you really want.